# Will I get video from the motherboard if the CPU doesn't have a GPU

Tags: video, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, gpu

Old motherboards like M4A88 series have an integrated video but the current ones have the connectors like HDMI and or DVI but Does them have an integrated video or those connectors only works if the CPU have a GPU integrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current market, the video processing unit can be on the motherboard *and/or* on the CPU itself. The fact that a motherboard has a video output connector (with any standard such as HDMI or DVI) does **not** necessary mean that the motherboard has an integrated video processing unit.

Motherboards targeted to CPUs the *possibility* for an integrated GPU on the CPU in general **don't** have a video chip (but they *can* have video connectors, but they won't work without a CPU with integrated GPU).

Two CPU examples:

- the [AMD Ryzen 7 2700U mobile with RADEON™ RX VEGA 10 graphics](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-7-2700u) had obviously an integrated GPU on the CPU (targeted towards the laptop market).
- the [AMD Ryzen 7 2700X](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-2700x) has no integrated GPU.

Two motherboard examples:

- the [Asus RoG Crosshair VII Hero](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-CROSSHAIR-VII-HERO-WI-FI/) is targeted for such a market that a separate GPU is assumed, so it has no video output connectors.
- the [Asus RoG Strix X470-F Gaming](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-X470-F-GAMING/) has a HDMI and a DisplayPort connector, but no integrated video chip.